Metropolis sampling for large dimension
Let $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2)$ be the variable of interest with density $p_{\theta}$. We assume that the density, along with marginal densities $p_{\theta_1}$ and $p_{\theta_2}$, are known but difficult to generate. I decide to use Metropolis algorithm to sample $\theta$. Let us say I use a normal proposal distribution with identity matrix as covariance and the current value as mean.
I have two options : one is to use the normal distribution with the dimension equal to the one of $\theta$, and generate directly $\theta$ using proposal distribution. Another choice is to use some kind of Metropolis-in-Gibbs algorithm, which uses a Metropolis step in $\theta_1$ and then a Metropolis step on $\theta_2$.
Generally speaking, which one is more efficient ? In practice I feel like the first one is less efficient and has lower accepting probability. But is there any justification?

Using a Normal random walk Metropolis on each component with the conditionals as targets can prove more efficient than a joint Normal random walk Metropolis on the full vector in case of strong anisotropies/correlations between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. The comparison can be run by checking the acceptance rates of both schemes, although a lower acceptance rate is not necessarily a signal for less efficiency.
